# Does QuantLib have functionality to value ILS Telbor swaps?

Tags: quantlib

I didn't find the ILS Telbor class in QuantLib website and also reference online. Please let me know if we can value such swaps using QuantLib. For example `ql.Euribor6M()`, `ql.GBPLibor(ql.Period('1M'))`, etc.

Comment: It's a really bad design to need a code change and a new class just to add a new index or currency.

Comment: I completely agree.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no predefined Telbor class, but those are just for convenience.
You can define your index with:

```
telbor6m = ql.IborIndex(
    "Telbor",
    ql.Period(6, ql.Months),
    fixing_days,
    ql.ILSCurrency(),
    ql.Israel(),
    rolling_convention,
    end_of_month,
    day_counter,
    forecast_handle
)
```

I haven't researched what the fixing days and the other conventions are; you can fill them in.  The same works in C++.

Comment: Great. According to https://assets.bbhub.io/professional/sites/10/ILS-TELBOR-Fixed-to-Floating-Swap-Contract.pdf Attachment A, both legs use Actual/365.